# Kummer map on the formal group of elliptic curve

Tags: elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology, kummer-theory, formal-groups

In section 3(Page 50) of this [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20170922213351id_/http://homepages.mcs.vuw.ac.nz/%7Ebdkim/Parity.pdf), it is mentioned that the Kummer map, $\hat{E}(\mathfrak{m}_n)\rightarrow H^{1}(k_n,T)$ along with the Weil pairing induces a cup product of Galois cohomology groups. How is the Kummer map defined? I know that $\hat{E}(\mathfrak{m}_n)$ injects into $E(k_n)$ and then somehow the Kummer sequence for elliptic curves is involved to get a map to $H^{1}(k_n,T)$? Can someone help?